# How to retrieve multiple username from Firestore and assign the username to the correct markers on map

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

The code shown below is the code used to retrieve the multiple users location from Realtime Firebase and assign to the markers on map:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference userLocationRef = db.child("User_Location");

    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            userLocationRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        try {
                            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                                String userID = String.valueOf(ds.child("userID").getValue());

                                String encryptedLatitude = ds.child("You").child("l").child("0").getValue(String.class);
                                String  encryptedLongitude = ds.child("You").child("l").child("1").getValue(String.class);
                                Log.d("encryptedLocation", encryptedLatitude + ", " + encryptedLongitude); //Check the values
                                Log.d("userid", userID); //Check the values

                               


                                //decrypt
                                LocationEncryption locationEncryption = new LocationEncryption();
                                String decryptedLatitude = null;
                                String decryptedLongitude = null;


                                decryptedLatitude = locationEncryption.decrypt(encryptedLatitude);
                                decryptedLongitude = locationEncryption.decrypt(encryptedLongitude);

                                Log.d("Decrypted", decryptedLatitude + ", " + decryptedLongitude); //Check the values

                                double lat = Double.valueOf(decryptedLatitude);
                                double lng = Double.valueOf(decryptedLongitude);

                                //Add location on Google Map
                                LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);


                                if (hm.containsKey(userID)) {
                                    hm.get(userID).remove();
                                }

                                currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(userID));
                                currentLocationMarker.showInfoWindow();
                                hm.put(userID, currentLocationMarker);



                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

The structure of the real-time firebase is as follow:
[image: realtime firebase]

The result of the code is as follow:
[image: result]

When I click on the marker, it only shows the userID of the user. I want the marker to show the name of the user together with the userID. But the problem is that the multiple users' names are stored in Firestore.

The structure of the Firestore is as follow:
[image: Firestore]
[image: firestore]
The admin details and the user details are stored in the same collection "Users". The fields "isAdmin" and "isUser" are the method to differentiate them. I only need the username and the admin name is not required.

So, how to retrieve multiple users' names from Firestore and assign the names to the correct markers on the map.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You are using code for reading data from the Realtime Database while the screenshots show a Firestore database. So which exact database are you using?

Comment: The usernames and user emails are stored in the Firestore while the locations of users are stored. The code that I use to retrieve data from firebase is just to show the concept of the application, there is not much problem.

Comment: The problem is that how to retrieve the username from firestore and assign them to the correct markers on the map. For now, I just can show the userID when I click on the marker. Hope you can understand what I m trying to say. Thanks

Comment: You are getting the `userID` from the Realtime Database. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have updated the question by uploading an image of the structure of the real-time firebase. I m not sure how to upload the JSON file of the real-time firebase structure to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I click on the marker, it only shows the userID of the user. I want the marker to show the name of the user together with the userID.

The best option that you have is to store the name of the user right near the userID. There is no need to create another database call to only get the name of the user. So your new database schema should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- User_Location
       |
       --- $uid
            |
            --- userID: "Jk8i...1jy2"
            |
            --- userName: "Zi Zian Yeo"
```

And in code should look like this:

```
String userID = ds.child("userID").getValue(String.class);
String userName = ds.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
```

And to add these values as a title of the marker please use the following lines of code:

```
String title = userID + "/" + userName;
currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(title));
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later. I have a question here. Is it possible to bring the image from firebase storage and add the image on the marker once I click on it?

Comment: Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Yes, you can change the marker icon with one of your own.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. I will comment here if I face any problems about it.

Comment: Is there everything alright? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thanks, sir, it works. I will try to retrieve the image from the firebase storage and assign it to the marker on the map. If i face any problem, I will post a question here.